# Preparing manuscript for journal (pdflatex and bibtex)

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I am preparing to submit to a journal using a template downloaded from the "LaTeX" hyperlink at (https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/pages/submission_online). This downloads a .zip file called cabios.template.zip.

This .zip file contains .sty files, main.tex file, and main.bib file. It also contains a Sample.pdf file. I am unsure how to convert the main.tex file to look like the Sample.pdf file. So, far, I tried this approach:

```
pdflatex main
bibtex main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

The bibtex command resulted in two Errors:

```
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
```

It seems the main.bbl file is empty. On another part of their site, they state: "If you use bibtex, please use the bibliography style named natbib.bst". So, I also tried:

```
pdflatex main
bibtex natbib
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

And received a message:

```
I couldn't open file name `natbib.aux'
```

When I try the code above, I am able to generate a file main.pdf. However, it looks different than Sample.pdf, especially with text and corner lines in the margins. I am trying to make sure I use the correct conversion of main.tex to main.pdf, so that I am following the expected format correctly.

Any advice is greatly appreciated (and sorry if this is a newbie question).

Comment: If you use `latexmk -pdf main.tex`, it will automate this for you, provided that the commands in `main.tex` incorporate the bibliography appropriately.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no `natbib.bst` that I know of. You should do `bibtex main`, anyhow; an empty `.bbl` file may mean no `\cite` command in your document.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is correct:

```
pdflatex main
bibtex main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

And @pentavalentcarbon's suggestion works too:

```
latexmk -pdf main.tex
```

The error:

> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
>
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux

means that there is no `\cite` command (or similar, like `\citet` or `\citep`) in the document. This means that there is no need to run bibtex.

The .bbl file is empty, as you noted, because there is no `\cite` in the main document.

Once you start to write your manuscript the error will disappear and the .bbl file will be written as needed.

As for the difference between the `sample.pdf` and the `main.pdf`, it's not your fault. The `sample.pdf` was produced with a different source file, so it will not be exactly equal.